# manage session data for all users in spring 3.0

Tags: java, spring, security, session, spring-mvc

as the title says, i've got a spring mvc security implementation, works great, but i would like to manage the user log in inside the web application.

I would need to add session info like "client ip address, time logged-in, last activity of the user and log-in status (if i want to log them out)"

I've read a lot of forums, examples, even spring documentation, and couldn't find what i need.

Even tried adding beans to my security xml, adding a @Resource sessionManager in the LoginController of mine, and got a 504 error.

Another question: Is there a way to obtain the client IP address? i'm getting it by doing a post to another website using jquery right now... but that's pretty dirty.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

In order in operate on 'all sessions', you'll need to be 'higher' than the sessions, which means the ApplicationContext.

I did something kinda sorta similar some time back by extending ServletContextListener and adding a listener definition to web.xml.

Basically:
In contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent event) add an instance of your listener with

```
event.getServletContext().setAttribute("myContextListener", this);
```

when you need something, get the object out of the Context with some variation of

```
(MyContextListener)request.getSession().getServletContext()
    .getAttribute("myContextListener");
```

As to how to do it 'The Spring Way'(tm), well, I dunno...yet.